# Best way to pass value from focus to blur function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur

I'm trying to pass function from focus function to blur function. If value is the same I do not have to run additional validation. If value is different then I would send the ajax call and make sure that value not already exist in database. One way to do this would be with global variable. Is there other way to achieve this with JavaScript/JQuery? Here is example:

```js
var defaultNumber;
$(".check-number").focus(function() {
    defaultNumber = $(this).val();
}).blur(function() {
    var currNumber = $(this).val();
    
    if(currNumber !== defaultNumber){
      console.log('Send request...');
      /*
      Ajax call that checks if value already exist in database.
      */
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control check-number" name="frm_number" id="frm_number" maxlength="2" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}" title="Number field allows alphanumeric characters only (must be two characters length) - no other special characters" placeholder="Example: 07" value="99"
    required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the old value as data attribute on focus, and compare the current value with the data attribute on blur.

```js
var defaultNumber;
$(".check-number").focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-prev', $(this).val());
}).blur(function() {
    var currNumber = $(this).val();
    
    if(currNumber !== $(this).attr('data-prev')){
      console.log('Send request...');
      /*
      Ajax call that checks if value already exist in database.
      */
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control check-number" name="frm_number" id="frm_number" maxlength="2" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}" title="Number field allows alphanumeric characters only (must be two characters length) - no other special characters" placeholder="Example: 07" value="99"
    required>
</div>
```

Comment: This was the answer with correct solution. I tried other proposed solutions but they did not work. Can you please explain how `this` is able to keep the data attribute from the previous object?

Comment: @espresso_coffee `this` reference the text input itself, data attribute is associated with the input so you can access it the same way as you access other attributes/properties. In this case, you update 'data-prev' each time the input got focus, and use the value for comparison after the input lost focus.

Answer (score 1):

No need to store it, there is [defaultValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

```js
var defaultNumber;
$(".check-number").blur(function() {
    console.log(this.defaultValue!==this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control check-number" name="frm_number" id="frm_number" maxlength="2" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}" title="Number field allows alphanumeric characters only (must be two characters length) - no other special characters" placeholder="Example: 07" value="99"
    required>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `defaultValue` available only for focus and blur case or it can be used in some other situations as well?